# does anyone know if it is possible to get the values of multiple entites using LUIS.AI and Flow?

Tags: sharepoint, azure-language-understanding, power-automate

I am currently working in a project using LUIS.AI and flow in order to extract data from an Email and then using flow to save the data into a Sharepoint list. However, I am stuck because I need to get a multiple values from the same entity. In this case, the email contains multiple tracking numbers and my entity named TrackingNo is able to identify all of them, however I am not able to retrieve them all from ms flow. I only get one value although if I use match entity count is able to read the 4 tracking numbers containing in the email so the question here is if one of you have been able to get multiple values from the same entity from one Luis intent.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information? What was the text, how did you define the entities, were you using authoring 2.x or 3.x?